# How to convert a char to int and vice versa?

Tags: java

Okay I need to be able to convert

"MEET YOU IN THE PARK"

into

12 4 4 19 |     24 14 20 |     8 13  |  19 7 4  |    15 0 17 10

And be able to convert it back again.

What I have currently is

```
    int number, result;
    String input;

    System.out.println("Enter the Code: ");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    //input = s.nextLine();
    number = s.nextInt();

    input = Integer.toString(number);

    System.out.println(input);
```

Some of it is commented out or not used because i was playing around. Any help would be a miracle thank you!

Comment: Do you have a mapping between the numbers and alphabets?

Comment: Yes, by what logic do you expect uppercase `M` to map to 14?  It's clearly not ASCII (or Unicode).  So the current answers suggesting to interpret the individual `char`s as `int`s won't give you what you have asked for.

Comment: @5gon12eder It's the position in the alphabet (zero-based).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Enter the Code: ");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String fromUser = s.next();

for (int i=0; i<fromUser.length(); i++){
     int charValue = (int)fromUser.charAt(i);//will give you the char unicode value
}
```

To get the opposite is:

```
char opp = (char)<int value of the char>;
```

Comment: I added a System.out.print(charValue); but got really weird numbers:
Meet =
77101101116

Comment: nevermind, as people commented, the correct Unicode isn't the numbers i needed, so i just subtracted it by 65 to get my numbers

Comment: great.. please update your vote

Comment: there is no such thing as char(intValue); Did you mean to cast the int to a char?

Comment: updating to the right answer

Comment: Ya i'm having trouble with changing the int to the chars as I can't figure out what needs to be a string and what needs to be an int

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
for (char c: "MEET YOU IN THE PARK".toCharArray()) {
    System.out.print(c == ' '? "|": c- 'A');
    System.out.print(' ');
}
```

Comment: If the string is not hard-coded but user input, it might be necessary converting it to upper-case beforehand or using a more elaborate case selection.  (Also for handling newlines, tabs and such but the OP didn't mention these so probably it's not a requirement.)

Answer (score -2):

```
String s = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
for(Char c : s.toCharArray()){
    if(c == ' ')
        System.out.println("|");
    else
        System.out.println(c - "A");// convert to int and set offset.
}
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but doesn't match the requirements.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this answer seems useless. It's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: Oh... he wanted the position of the character in the alphabet...